# How to import a text file with '|' delimited data to PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, csv, import

I have a text file with `|` delimited data that I want to import to a table in PostgreSQL database. PgAdminIII only exports CSV files. I converted the file to a CSV file but still was unsuccessful importing data to PostgreSQL database. It says an error has occurred:

```
Extradata after last expected column. 
CONTEXT: COPY <file1>, line1:
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: It seems that the structure of the CSV file didn't match that of the PostgreSQL table, you should post an extract of the first few lines of the file and the schema of the table if you want to get a proper answer.

Comment: For starters, to ask a serious question, you *need* to provide your PostgreSQL version, the *full* command you are using, some sample data and the table definition.

Comment: HI Erwin, I am using postgress.app (postgres 9.2.4). Then I used pgadminIII to import the csv file.

Answer (score 1):

Using the standard `psql` shell you can do this:

```
\copy table_name from 'filename' delimiter '|'
```

In the shell you can do

```
\h copy
```

to see more options and the complete syntax. Of course the manual about [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html) is also worthwhile reading.